# Значение «в качестве» или значение причины?

Tags: пунктуация, оборот-с-как

***Группа торопливо засмеялась, зная, что Замрушев  как истинный комик ценит только благодарную аудиторию.***

Контекст: Он был, пожалуй, самым забавным преподвавателем на биофаке. Его занятия походили на клоунаду.

Здесь оборот с союзом КАК не обособлен, но тогда по правилам он должен иметь **значение «в качестве».**

Но мне кажется, что здесь больше подходит **значение причины** (будучи истинным комиком).
Как объяснить отсутствие обособления? Может быть, оборот нужно обособить?

Или возможны варианты, но как их разичить по смыслу и правильно выбрать нужный?

Спасибо.

**Правила:**

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

**ПАС, § 64.** Обособляются запятыми приложения, имеющие при себе присоединяющие их слова (по имени, по фамилии, по прозвищу, по происхождению, родом и др.), а также союзы КАК **(при осложненности причинным значением)**: Как лицо служебное, милицейское, Сошнин привык знакомиться с разным народом (Аст.);

**Примечание 2.** Приложение с союзом КАК надо отличать от оборота **со значением «в качестве»**. Ср.: Он, как инженер, должен быть руководителем стройки (будучи инженером, должен руководить; приложение). — Он приехал на стройку как инженер (в качестве инженера).

**Также у Розенталя:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

7. Обособленное приложение может присоединяться союзом КАК (**с дополнительным значением причинности),** а также словами по имени, по фамилии, по прозвищу, родом и др. (**независимо от того, какой частью речи выражено определяемое слово**): Илюше иногда, как резвому мальчику, так и хочется броситься и переделать всё самому (Гонч.); Как старый артиллерист, я презираю этот вид холодного украшения (Ш.); Леонтьев увлёкся этой мыслью, но, как человек осторожный, пока что о ней никому не рассказывал (Пауст

**Примечание.** Если союз КАК  имеет значение **‘в качестве’**, то присоединяемый им оборот обособляется: Полученный ответ рассматривается как согласие (Аж.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шарончик дорогой, не "в качестве" и не "причины": банальный сравнительный оборот.

Наш герой - преподаватель на биофаке, а занятия только ***походят*** на клоунаду, не будучи таковой по определению.

*Группа торопливо засмеялась, зная, что Замрушев, как истинный комик, ценит только благодарную аудиторию.*

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо! С Новым годом вас, вего вам наилучшего! Честно говоря, такая мысль мне не приходила в голову и даже близко к ней не подходила.  Пока  я только наполовину согласна, надо еще подумать. Но зато очень благодарна вам за ответ.

Comment: Даёшь вторую половину - автопробегом по бездорожью!

Comment: Давайте так. Вы прочитаете полный портрет «клоунадного  преподавателя» (глава 3, всего пара страниц, со слов  «Картухин! Где ваша последняя лабораторная?.. Картухин, ау!» и до слов «Сам не понял, что сказал, но звучит умно. Все! Свободны! Можете деградировать!».  И если не измените своего мнения, то я верю вам, как себе.

https://read-book-online.com/fentezi/320133-kniga-semi-dorog.html?page=9

Comment: Просто мне кажется, что его истинным призванием была именно клоунада, а не педагогика.

Comment: Шаронка, щас как стукну. Какая разница, истинное то было призвание или фантом. Факт: учился на биолога, дорос до преподавателя. А там - хоть горшком назови, всё будет сравнение.

Comment: Всё, вы меня убедили, согласна на все сто.

Comment: Шаронушка, увидела случайно, без "извещений", твой тёплый коммент к моей немудрёной поздравлялке, - спасибо! )))

Comment: Да, письмо было "на деревню дедушке", надо было адрес поставить, тогда фонарик бы зажегся. На досуге займусь вашим ребусом, спасибо.